# JQuery Sortable with fixed row

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

In [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shuklendu/uacc7/17/)

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
    cancel: ".fixed"
});
$("#sortable").disableSelection();
```

this example the item 3,5 are fixed but when i moved Item 7 to above to Item 3 Item 3 Changes it position to 4, i want it to remain in 3rd position(Item 3 and Item 7) rest of Items can drag and drop by the user.
How can i achieve this functionality?

Comment: Two separate sortables around the "fixed" rows, and make them Connected Lists http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists ?

Answer (score 0):

Half solution is http://jsfiddle.net/wa1grxrh/1/

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
    cancel: ".fixed",
    start: function(event, ui) {
        var start_pos = ui.item.index();
        ui.item.data('last_pos', start_pos);
    },
    change: function(event, ui) {
        var last_pos = ui.item.data('last_pos'),
            index = ui.placeholder.index(),
            options = $(this).data().sortable.options;
        if (last_pos > index) {
            $(options.items, $(this)).slice(index, last_pos + 1).filter(options.cancel).each(function(ix) {
                $(this).prevAll().not('.ui-sortable-placeholder').first().detach().insertAfter(this);
            });
        } else if (last_pos < index) {
            $(options.items, $(this)).slice(last_pos, index + 1).filter(options.cancel).each(function(ix) {
                $(this).nextAll().not('.ui-sortable-placeholder').first().detach().insertBefore(this);
            });
        }
        ui.item.data('last_pos', ui.placeholder.index());
    },
});
$("#sortable").disableSelection();
```

But it doesn't work if any fixed item is first or last or several fixed items are in a row.

I'm affraid full solution is required to modify sortable module. It's needed to prevent the placeholder putting between fixed items or in the edge of item list.